# Is there a way to install Gnome Themes with the terminal?

Tags: command-line, themes, gnome-shell

Just like there is a 'git clone' command, is there a command to download themes from **gnome-look(dot)org** website?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You ask about installing themes from the terminal (a simple `apt install theme_package` works), but then you talk about downloading a theme (totally different). If you just want to "clone" a package, then this will work: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-extract-a-deb-file-without-opening-it-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/.

Comment: If you know what the theme is, where located - I'd use `wget` to download & save where I want.  It assumes you already know where/what you want to grab (like git clone does)

Answer (score 0):

A theme as so called by gnome-look.org can include several themes:
 - Gnome shell theme
 - GTK+ theme (for windows)
 - Icons theme
 - Gnome shell extension(s)

So, manually installing a theme is manually installing each component.
Some theme providers build a `deb` package that make it easier to maintain

For example the Flat Remix theme is available as `deb` package on a `ppa`
See :
- https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013030/ 
- https://drasite.com/flat-remix-gnome

Installation of the Flat Remix theme goes like this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniruiz/flat-remix
# update not required since 18.04
# sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flat-remix-gnome
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use [gnome-theme-installer](https://github.com/Rishang/gnome-theme-installer).

To Install themes for current user

```
gnomelooks get [THEME-URL]
```

To Install themes globally

```
sudo gnomelooks get [THEME-URL]
```

Please also look at [Download files from gnome-look.org via CLI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/743891/206574) to understand the inner workings of gnome-look.org